# Pycord/discord.py slash commands not showing up

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py, pycord

Ive never had this issue before. All of my other bots work perfectly, and im convinced its not my source code. When I start my bot, i get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Overdrive\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 377, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Overdrive\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\discord\bot.py", line 1164, in on_connect
    await self.sync_commands()
  File "C:\Users\Overdrive\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\discord\bot.py", line 719, in sync_commands
    registered_commands = await self.register_commands(
  File "C:\Users\Overdrive\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\discord\bot.py", line 588, in register_commands
    data = [cmd["command"].to_dict() for cmd in filtered_deleted]
  File "C:\Users\Overdrive\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\discord\bot.py", line 588, in <listcomp>
    data = [cmd["command"].to_dict() for cmd in filtered_deleted]
  File "C:\Users\Overdrive\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\discord\commands\core.py", line 844, in to_dict
    "options": [o.to_dict() for o in self.options],
  File "C:\Users\Overdrive\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\discord\commands\core.py", line 844, in <listcomp>
    "options": [o.to_dict() for o in self.options],
  File "C:\Users\Overdrive\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\discord\commands\options.py", line 318, in to_dict
    "type": self.input_type.value,
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'value'
```

After the error, the bot starts but doesnt show any slash commands in the servers. I am using this invite link:

https://discord.com/api/oauth2/authorize?client_id=REDACTED&permissions=8&scope=bot%20applications.commands

here are my bot intents:
[image]

my code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import os

intents=discord.Intents.all()
client=commands.Bot(intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'\n\nSuccessfully logged into Discord as "{client.user}"\nAwaiting user input...')
    await client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.online, activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.playing, name="all by myself..."))

@client.slash_command()
async def lol(interaction: discord.Interaction, ctx: discord.ApplicationContext):
    await interaction.response.send_message("LOL")

client.run(os.environ.get("TOKEN"))
```

Any help is appreciated! For the life of me I cannot figure out whats happening.

Answer (score 2):

Your interaction parameters are wrong. Should be:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import os

intents=discord.Intents.all()
client=commands.Bot(intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'\n\nSuccessfully logged into Discord as "{client.user}"\nAwaiting user input...')
    await client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.online, activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.playing, name="all by myself..."))

@client.slash_command()
async def lol(ctx: discord.ApplicationContext):
    await ctx.response.send_message("LOL")

client.run(os.environ.get("TOKEN"))
```

Using your code with my changes allowed it to run without throwing an exception and I was able to invoke the `lol` slash command.

[Slash command docs](https://guide.pycord.dev/interactions/application-commands/slash-commands). Slash commands have the `ctx` (ApplicationContext) parameter and then other parameters are usually slash command options.

Answer (score 0):

You should try using the discord.app_commands library.

Here's your code updated:

```py
import discord
from discord import app_commands
import os

class prepareclient(discord.Client):
    def __init__(self): super().__init__(intents=discord.Intents.all())
    async def on_ready():
        print(f'\n\nSuccessfully logged into Discord as "{client.user}"\nAwaiting user input...')
        await client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.online, activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.playing, name="all by myself..."))
        await tree.sync()

client = prepareclient()
tree = app_commands.CommandTree(client)

@tree.command(name="lol", description=f"lol")
async def lol(inc: discord.Interaction):
    await inc.response.send_message("LOL")
    return

client.run(os.environ.get("TOKEN"))
```

I hope this helps.